# Contraction mapping on functional space

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

I had some major modifications in my previous question.

I first showed that $\tau$ satisfies Blackwell's conditions, which implies that $\tau$ is a contraction mapping.

$\tau$ takes a bounded continuous function $[0,1] \to [-M,M]$ as an input.

According to the definition of contraction mapping :

$$ d\big{(}\tau(v),\tau(u)\big{)} \leq \beta * d\big{(}v,u\big{)} $$
for some $\beta \in [0,1)$ and for any function $u$ and $v$. Here I will just assume $d$ is sup norm.

Now, I want to build up a function $v(x)$ likewise :

$$ v(x) \equiv u(f(x)) =  u \bigg{(} \frac{ax}{ax+(1-a)(1-x)}\bigg{)}$$

where $a>1/2$.

Note that $f(x) \geq x$ for any $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)\in[0,1]$.

Then, I can conclude:

$$ d\big{(}\tau(u(f)),\tau(u)\big{)} \leq \beta * d\big{(}u(f),u\big{)} $$

However, what I really want to show is that, for any $x\in[0,1]$,

$$ \big{|}\tau(u(f(x)))-\tau(u(x))\big{|} \leq \beta * \big{|}u(f(x))-u(x)\big{|} $$

The latter implies the former (just by imposing sup). If I want to reach to the latter statement, what additional sufficient conditions should be satisfied?

Comment: That's not the definition of contraction mapping on a function space, which in this case would require you to specify a metric on continuous functions (commonly done with the sup norm). Instead it appears to be a stronger condition of pointwise contraction.

Comment: You are completely right. I changed the notation to d|•|. 
Am I still missing something?

Comment: OK so first of all $\tau(u(x))$ makes no sense. It should be $\tau u\left(x\right)$ or even $\left(\tau u\right)\left(x\right)$. I tried to make the edit myself but it seems some bright spark rejected it. Let's write $u \in C[0,1]$ for $u:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ a continuous function. As I understand it your operator $\tau: C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ and $\tau u \in C[0,1]$. So you see it is $(\tau u)$ that is applied to $x$.

Comment: Yes exactly. I saw a notation $ \tau \circ v (x)$ somewhere, but please enlighten me what difference there is between $\tau(v(x))$ and $\tau v (x)$. I just wanted to empathsize that $\tau$ takes a function $v$ as an input. I will edit them as you suggested soon. 

At the end, is the logic correct?

Comment: I think with the parentheses correctly arranged your assertion $\left(\tau v\right)\left(x\right) = \left(\tau u\right)\left(x^{\text{up}}\right)$ is no longer obvious...

Comment: The problem with $\tau(u(x))$ is that $\tau$ is defined on functions, not numbers. But $u(x)$ is a number, not a function. $u$ is a function, but $u(x)$ is the value $u$ takes on at $x$, which is only a number. $\tau(u)(x), (\tau u)(x), \tau u(x)$ would all be appropriate ways of denoting what you want, which is first evaluate $\tau$ at the function $u$, which results in another function, and then evaluate that resultant function at $x$. ("$\tau u$" is a variant notation for $\tau(u)$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your interests. I changed my question trying to be more accurate on notations.